# Upload files using HTML POST -> API-> Lambda -> s3 - Amazon API Gateway p26

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, api, post, lambda

I already have code to upload one file to s3 via lambda/api
Its work with html post ""

I was based on youtube video tourial Amazon API Gateway p26

but now I wont to handle multiple files how I should handle it?

```
  <html>
    <title>Upload file</title>
    <h3>Upload file funk....</h3>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data", action="https://*********.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/v101/upload">
        
    Select File test2:
        <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
    
    </form>
    </html>
```

this is code of my lambda function

```
import json
import base64
import boto3
import email

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")

    
    post_data = base64.b64decode(event['body'])
    
    content_type = event["headers"]['content-type']
    
    ct = "Content-Type: "+content_type+"\n"

    # parsing message from bytes
    msg = email.message_from_bytes(ct.encode()+post_data)

    # checking if the message is multipart
    print("Multipart check : ", msg.is_multipart())
    
    # if message is multipart
    if msg.is_multipart():
        multipart_content = {}
        # retrieving form-data
        for part in msg.get_payload():
            # checking if filename exist as a part of content-disposition header
            if part.get_filename():
                # fetching the filename
                file_name = part.get_filename()
            multipart_content[part.get_param('name', header='content-disposition')] = part.get_payload(decode=True)


s3_upload = s3.put_object(Bucket="zdjeciatotxt", Key=file_name, Body=multipart_content["file"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I was passing multiple files in the body as form-data too, i was base64 encoding them, to get it as base64 in my Lambda function, then decoding it if necessary.

But it's not a really good practice when it comes to big files.

> Payload size  10 MB

API Gateway as a hard limit of 10MB for Payloads, so as soon as you reach it, it will fail.
What i do for big files is going through S3 directly.
The API call is linked to a Lambda that generates a signed URL, that is returned to the client, this way the client can directly upload the file to S3 whatever the size is. But you'll need to do multiple requests for multiples files, or return an array of URL, it's up to you. I think it's safer.

TL;DR
I think you need to configure your API settings (Requests mapping for example) to pass base64 data to your Lambda that you will decode.
If you ask me i think it's not really good practice when it comes to big files or a lot of files.